# MySQL exception: field '' does not have a default value

Tags: mysql, exception, default-value

I have a database table in MySQL 5.5 with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_relationships` (
  `_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `create_date` long NOT NULL,
  `update_date` long NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `related_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Yet when I run a query against the table I get the following exception:

```
Exception:   Save user_relationship record error on: insert into user_relationships(create_date, update_date, user_id, related_user_id) values(1421086506464, 1421086506464, 13, 13) - Adapter ExceptionMessage: SQLException: Field 'active' doesn't have a default value
```

The create statement defines a default value of -1:

```
`active` int(11) DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL ,
```

So, why is MySQL throwing this exception?   If I scrape the insert statement and run it from MySQL workbench it runs w/o exception.  I have also dropped the table and rebuilt it with this sql statement just to be sure this definition was being used.

**Edit**

messages from MySQL Workbench executing the create table statement:

```
12:14:05    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_relationships` (   `_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `create_date` long NOT NULL,   `update_date` long NOT NULL,   `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `related_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `active` int(11) DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL ,   PRIMARY KEY (`_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 0 row(s) affected   0.055 sec


12:14:05    CREATE INDEX ix_user_relationships__id ON user_relationships (_id) USING BTREE  0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0    0.057 sec

12:14:05    CREATE INDEX ix_user_relationships_user_id ON user_relationships (user_id) USING BTREE  0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0    0.059 sec

12:14:05    CREATE INDEX ix_user_relationships_related_user_id ON user_relationships (related_user_id) USING BTREE  0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0    0.064 sec
```

[image]

Comment: What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE user_relationships` return? Also, try changing the order `NOT NULL DEFAULT -1`.

Comment: `IF NOT EXISTS`, are you sure the table doesn't exist?

Comment: @JacobBudin  I have no doubt the table exists and the exception message supports the existence of the table and field.  It's just the default value is not getting applied properly.  Very strange.

Comment: @MarcusAdams  I have edited my post to answer your question.  :^)

Comment: @MarcusAdams  Originally that is the way the create statement was written `active` `int(11)NOT NULL  DEFAULT -1 ,` with same effect.